# Keycloak implementation in spring boot (microservices) and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, authentication, keycloak, user-management

Best regards, I am working on a Spring Boot and Angular application with Keycloak for security. You have successfully implemented login using the keycloak-angular library in Angular. Now, you are considering introducing microservices, particularly a microservice called "user". My dilemma is whether to continue using the keycloak-angular library for authentication in Angular while the microservice handles the creation of users, roles and privileges, or should I delegate the entire authentication and authorization process to the microservice

I am currently working on my undergraduate thesis in systems engineering in Colombia, using Spring Boot 3.1.4 and Angular 16.0.2 with Keycloak for security management.

Attached, you will find a microservices architecture diagram that I am developing. In my Angular application, I successfully implemented login functionality using the keycloak-angular library. Now, as I explore the idea of microservices in Spring Boot, particularly a microservice named "user," a question has arisen:

Should I discontinue the use of the keycloak-angular library when implementing microservices and entrust the entire authentication and authorization management to the new microservice? Or can I retain the keycloak-angular library for handling authentication while the microservice manages user creation, roles, and privileges?

I would greatly appreciate your guidance and any contacts you can provide for assistance with this matter.

Attached is the architecture diagram.[microservices architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uilTf.png)

Thank you for your time and support!